# Instance member cannot be used on instance of nested type between struct swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I am trying to pass the variable *code* from struct *FormularyDetail* to a nested struct *WebView* but keep on receiving error of

> Instance member 'code' of type 'FormularyDetail' cannot be used on instance of nested type 'FormularyDetail.WebView'.

My swift code is as below:

```
struct FormularyDetail: View {
    var drugmaster: DrugMaster
    var code: String  {
        get {
            return drugmaster.code
        }
    }

    let testHTML = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "www/index", withExtension: "html")
    struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
        
        let request: URLRequest
        static var codein: String {
            get {
                return FormularyDetail.code //I got the error on this line
            }
        }
...
```

Any help are appreciated.

Comment: Nesting type definitions doesn't give you access to outer type properties. Think of them as two unrelated types. If you need access to `code`, you'd need to pass it in, for example, via `init`

Comment: Even if accessing properties from the enclosing type would be possible, you’re left with the problem on trying to access instance properties from a static context, which is not possible. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although some languages do allow nested types to access instance members of the enclosing type, Swift is not one of them.  The nested type is a distinct type.  The main advantages to nesting a type have to do with encapsulating it.  It effectively provides a name space for it, allowing you to use simpler names without collision with types of the same name nested in other types.  It also allows you to make them private to the type, when they are an implementation detail.

With that in mind, the answer to how you access the enclosing type's instance properties is same as if it were defined at global scope.  Namely, you inject it.  Pass the value in when you initialize it.

Since the code you provide is clearly for SwiftUI views, you'll need to consider whether `WebView` needs to dynamically respond to updates to `drugmaster.code`, and use `@State` or `@StateObject` accordingly.